# Why is syphilis not resistant to penicilin?

Tags: medicine, antibiotic-resistance

How is it that we are dealing with so many antiobiotic resistant infections in iatrogenic settings, and yet this very old bacterial pathogen has still not acquired resistance to penicilin (the oldest antibiotic to which it has had the longest relative exppsure to)??

Comment: While rare, it does happen--reports of penicillin-resistance go back [to at least 1949](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamadermatology/fullarticle/522301)

Answer (score -1):

First off, Treponema Pallidum-the bacteria which causes Syphilis-is EXTREMELY SENSITIVE to Pencillin; even a small does can wipe them out! Secondly, since Syphilis has been around for centuries without mutating into a form immune to Pencillin this suggests TP doesn’t have ANY protective measures against antibiotics-making it highly susceptible. Lastly, resistance rates remain low globally, meaning strains which develop immunity don’t survive long against antibiotic treatment